# calling javascript function with an argument from html

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a html element using javascript:

```
html_info +=    '<div class="row"><h4>'+ i +'. Patient: '+ key +'</h4>Date of birth: '+info[0]+'<br> Occupation: '+info[1]+'<br> Date of Test: ' + info[2]+ '<script type="text/javascript"> draw_chart(' + patient_test_info[key].right_eye +' ); </script></div>';

document.getElementById('patient_display').innerHTML += html_info;
```

It creates the element properly and displays the information stored in `info` array, but call to the draw_chart() function fails. I printed the contents of `patient_test_info[key].right_eye` using console.log before passing it as an argument and the contents of the variable are fine. But checking the html elements displays that `patient_test_info[key].right_eye` is not passed correctly and are just empty objects.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> draw_chart([object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ); </script>
```

My draw_chart() function must draw the chart in the same div as the one used to display `info` content. On calling it independently, it does not recognise the newly created div and thus does not display anything.

```
function draw_chart(data)  {

    var chart = d3.cloudshapes.barChart()
        .width(800).height(800);

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)  {
        var temp_value = data[i];
        d3.select("#row")
            .datum(temp_value)
            .call(chart);
    }
}
```

What is the right way of calling the function using an argument ?

Comment: You can't pass objects like that, when concantenating the object with a string, the object is also turned into a string, and the string representation of an object is `[object Object]`.

The question is, why do you insert a script tag that calls a function immediately, why not just call the function ?

Comment: @adeneo I tried it, `html_info +=  '<div class="row"><h4>'+ i +'. Patient: '+ key +'</h4>Date of birth: '+info[0]+'<br> Occupation: '+info[1]+'<br> Date of Test: ' + info[2]; draw_chart(patient_test_info[key].right_eye) +'</div>';` , but it again displays an empty string.

Comment: You're not getting it, why do you include the function in the string, you're already executing javascript, why not just call the function directly, why do you have to insert it into the DOM and then call it, when you can call it right a way

Comment: @adeneo I got that now, thanks !

Comment: @adeneo I tried calling it independently, but then the draw_chart() does not recognise the newly created id. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What adeneo is saying is if you call the function directly it should work, like this:

```
html_info += '<div class="row"><h4>'+ i +'. Patient: '+ key +'</h4>Date of birth: '+info[0]+'<br> Occupation: '+info[1]+'<br> Date of Test: ' + info[2] + draw_chart(patient_test_info[key].right_eye) + '</div>';
```

In response to your comment, I don't know how the chart code you're using works, but if `d3.select("#row")` is supposed to be targeting the div you've created, then you have 3 problems:

1) You're calling the function before the div has actually been added to the DOM. You need to do your `html_info += '<div class="row">...'` and `....innerHTML += html_info;` first, *then* call draw_chart() afterwards.

2) You're targetting the `<div class="row">` with `select("#row")` - assuming standard syntax, # denotes an ID, not a class. You either need to make it `id="row"` or `select(".row")` (a dot denotes a class). However, if you're planning to be able to call this function multiple times to add multiple charts, you'll need them to have unique names, otherwise you'll have trouble specifying that you want to use the *latest* row. I suggest using the ID and adding your "key" to it, assuming that's valid.

3) Again, I'm not sure how the chart code works, but I'd guess that it's going to replace the contents of the targetted div, not append to it, which means you'll lose the title from your row. If that's the case, I'd suggest putting another div inside your row div and giving it the name instead so you can target it, e.g. `'<div><h4>'+ i +'. Patient: '+ key +'</h4>Date of birth: '+info[0]+'<br> Occupation: '+info[1]+'<br> Date of Test: ' + info[2] + '<div id="chart-' + key + '"></div></div>'`. Once you've added that to the innerHTML, you can then call `draw_chart(patient_test_info[key].right_eye, key)` and modify your draw_chart method to use the key for the name, e.g. `d3.select("#chart-" + key)`.

Comment: This format does not work, it just displays `undefined` next to the last `info[2]` instance. I have edited the question, could you please suggest anything in that regards.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the issue more now, I've edited my answer. If that doesn't work we may need to see more of your code to be able to help - i.e. enough code that we can try it for ourselves and check the problem.

Comment: It was the 3rd error mentioned by you that my draw_chart() was replacing the content of the div rather than appending to it. Thanks a lot :)